# AVcaptureMetadataOutput does not work in ios10

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I used the `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` for a barcode scanner and it worked perfect. But since iOS 10 it does not working anymore. I always get a **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error when I open the `barcodescanner` with it´s button. The error occurs when I add an output to the session.

Can someone help me please? I really tried everything and it drives me crazy.

Comment: Add your code! Give more details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my Objective-C, which is working fine under iOS 10. IIRC I think I had trouble if the vars were only local to the method. Ensure all your vars are properties.

```
- (void)initialiseVideoSession {

    _session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    _device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;

    _input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:_device error:&error];

    if (_input) {

        [_session addInput:_input];

        _output = [[AVCaptureMetadataOutput alloc] init];
        [_output setMetadataObjectsDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        [_session addOutput:_output];

        _output.metadataObjectTypes = [_output availableMetadataObjectTypes];

        _prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:_session];
        _prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
        _prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:_prevLayer];

        [_session startRunning];

    } else {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my line which is works currently.

```
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
    // Get the first object from the metadataObjects array.
    if let barcodeData = metadataObjects.first {
        // Turn it into machine readable code
        let barcodeReadable = barcodeData as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;
        if let readableCode = barcodeReadable {
            // Send the barcode as a string to barcodeDetected()
            barcodeDetected(readableCode.stringValue);
        }
        // Vibrate the device to give the user some feedback.
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        // Avoid a very buzzy device.
        session.stopRunning()
    }
}
```